# Can I release my own work with CreativeCommon BY-NC-SA license (Non Commercial), and still make a commercial use myself?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I have released works with MIT licence, others with CC BY-SA, etc.

But for a specific work, I'd like to share it with Creative Commons BY-SA-NC, i.e. I don't want people who will modify/fork it to make a commercial use of it.

**Can I still sell this software (or service linked to it) myself?**

I read that having one "public" license (here CC BY-SA-NC) does not forbid me to re-license to other people (here, to myself!) with *other conditions*, since I am the author and copyright-owner of the work.

Does this apply here?

Or would the fact I do a commercial use *myself* break the "public" CC BY-SA-NC license of my work?

---

Examples of open source projects having multiple licensing for the same work: [Sqlite Copyright](https://sqlite.org/copyright.html)

Comment: Yes, you can re-license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are the sole copyright holder, you are not bound by any license and therefor you also cannot violate a license.

This rule is what gives you the right to give a work to different people under different licenses and it also gives you the right to commercially exploit your work even when you forbid others to do likewise.

The catch is, that if you accept contributions from others, then you become bound by the license terms under which you accept the contributions. You can accept contributions under a different license than the one you use to offer your work to others, but you must have a very clear, written, agreement between you and the contributor under what license you are accepting the contribution before you can do so.